# Python Telethon multiprocessing implementation

Tags: python, multiprocessing, telethon

I need to download many files (More than 1 GB) from telegram group, with telethon and single call the download is slow... (Abount 5, 6 Mbps) I have already installed cryptg but no changes...

Thanks a lot
Stefano

This is my example code tring to using multiprocessing and download many files concurrently but won't work... some suggestion?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from multiprocessing import Pool
from datetime import datetime
import time
import threading
import os


# Remember to use your own values from my.telegram.org!
api_id = HiddenByME
api_hash = 'HiddenByME'
bot_token= 'HiddenByME'

client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)
bot= TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)

movieschanneltofix = HiddenByME
movieschannelfixed = HiddenByME

downloadpath = "media/"

# Printing download progress
def callbackdownload(current, total):
    global start_time
    global end_time
    delta = (datetime.now()- start_time).total_seconds()
    bytes_remaining = total - current
    speed = round(((current / 1024) / 1024) / delta, 2)
    seconds_left = round(((bytes_remaining / 1024) / 1024) / float(speed), 2)
    print('Downloaded', round(current/1000000,2), 'out of', round(total/1000000,2),'Megabytes {:.2%}'.format(current / total), "->", "Trascorso:", round(delta/60, 2), " Minuti * Rimanente:", int(seconds_left), "Secondi * Velocità:", round(speed, 2), "Mbps",  end='\r')
# Printing Upload Progress
def callbackupload(current, total):
    global start_time
    global end_time
    delta = (datetime.now()- start_time).total_seconds()
    bytes_remaining = total - current
    speed = round(((current / 1024) / 1024) / delta, 2)
    seconds_left = round(((bytes_remaining / 1024) / 1024) / float(speed), 2)
    print('Uploaded', round(current/1000000,2), 'out of', round(total/1000000,2),'Megabytes {:.2%}'.format(current / total), "->", "Trascorso:", round(delta/60, 2), " Minuti * Rimanente:", int(seconds_left), "Secondi * Velocità:", round(speed, 2), "Mbps",  end='\r')


async def moviefix(results):
    global end_time
    global start_time
    print("Fixing Message ID: ", results.split(';')[0], "\n", "OldName: ", results.split(';')[1], "\n", "NewName: ", results.split(';')[2])

    # Get Message and Download Media Renaming It
    downpath = downloadpath+results.split(';')[2]
    start_time = datetime.now()
    print("Download Avviato:", start_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
    path = await client.download_media(await client.get_messages(movieschanneltofix, ids=int(results.split(';')[0])), downpath, progress_callback=callbackdownload)
    print('Download Completato!!! ', path)
    time.sleep(1)

    #Upload Renamed File
    start_time = datetime.now()
    print("Upload Avviato:", start_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
    result = await bot.send_file(movieschannelfixed, downpath, force_document=True, progress_callback=callbackupload)
    print('Upload Completato!!! ', result.file.name)
    time.sleep(1)

    #Delete Uploaded File
    os.remove(downpath)
    time.sleep(1)

    #Save Fixed File in DB
    with open('data/lastmoviefixed.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(results+"\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    time.sleep(20)
    return results


#    print (results, "PID:", os.getpid())
#    with open('data/lastmoviefixed.txt', 'a') as f:
#        f.write(results+"\n")
#        time.sleep(1)
#    time.sleep(10)
#    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global listtodo
    listtodo = set(open('data/listtofix.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8").read().splitlines()) - set(open('data/lastmoviefixed.txt', encoding="utf8").read().splitlines())
    with Pool(1) as p:
        result = p.map_async(client.loop.run_until_complete(moviefix), sorted(listtodo))
        while not result.ready():
            time.sleep(1)
        result = result.get()
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
    print("Done", results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use multiprocessing for CPU-bound operations. For I/O-bound operations, you can use async.io to run requests concurrently. however , concurrency is most beneficial when network bandwidth is not the limiting factor, such as when sending many requests. In the case of downloading files, if you hit the maximum network bandwidth, you will receive minimal benefit from concurrency.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!!! My connection Is 2.5 Gbps so it's not a network limit, could you provide me and example based on my program?